# Populate DataGridView from ComboBox.SelectedItem on Button click

Tags: winforms, datagridview, combobox, vb.net-2010

I have one ComboBox which is populated on load from populate.txt file. I'm using streamreader for this. So far it works. The ComboBox is properly populated with:

```
 - one
 - two
 - three
```

I have one empty TextBox, and a button.

The thing that I'm trying to do is:

- Select something from the ComboBox i.e. "one"
- Write in the TextBox i.e "50"
- Press the button, and to populate the DataGridView first row with:
  "One"(cell0) "50"(cell1)

At this point, a new empty row should be automatically added below the filled one. I've searched and searched for hours to no avail. So I decided to make an account and ask the question :)

The reason I'm doing this is that, later on I'll export the filled DataGridView.
I could easily use labels for this, but that's not what I'm aiming for. I'm  trying to "dive in" into the more complicated "stuff".

I hope that I explained well enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: How are you building your `DataGridView`?  If you post a code snippet showing your setup and how you currently populate a row on button click, a more concise answer may be given.

Comment: I'm not, that's the thing. I was trying to find a way to do it... But I've successfully did it by using ListBox instead of DataGridView, so I no longer need help.